# TypeError: transpose() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple), but expected one of: (int dim0, int dim1) or (name dim0, name dim1)

Tags: yolov5, kitti, adversarial-attack

I am trying to generate adversarial images using the FastGradientMethod attack in the ART library on a YOLOv5 object detection model. However, I am running into an error when attempting to generate the adversarial image using the fgm.generate() method. Specifically, I receive the following error message:

#### Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ben\OneDrive\pc\work\yolov5\FSGM.py", line 36, in 
adversarial_image_fgm = fgm.generate(image_np)
File "C:\Users\ben\OneDrive\pc\work\yolov5.venv\lib\site-packages\art\attacks\evasion\fast_gradient.py", line 312, in generate
y_array = self.estimator.predict(x, batch_size=self.batch_size)
File "C:\Users\ben\OneDrive\pc\work\yolov5.venv\lib\site-packages\art\estimators\object_detection\pytorch_object_detector.py", line 375, in predict
predictions = self._model(image_tensor_list)
File "C:\Users\ben\OneDrive\pc\work\yolov5.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ben\OneDrive\pc\work\yolov5.venv\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\ben/.cache\torch\hub\ultralytics_yolov5_master\models\common.py", line 689, in forward
im = im.transpose((1, 2, 0))  # reverse dataloader .transpose(2, 0, 1)
TypeError: transpose() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (tuple), but expected one of: (int dim0, int dim1) or (name dim0, name dim1)

#### Code:

```
import os
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms 
from torchvision.transforms import ToPILImage
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from art.estimators.object_detection import PyTorchObjectDetector
from art.attacks.evasion import FastGradientMethod, ProjectedGradientDescent

model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5','yolov5n')
# Initialize ART object detection estimator
estimator = PyTorchObjectDetector(model=model)

test_image_folder = 'data/KITTI/test/images'
output_folder = 'adversarial_images'

# Get list of image file names
image_filenames = os.listdir(test_image_folder)
image_filenames = [filename for filename in image_filenames if filename.endswith('.png')]

# Define the transformations to be applied to the images

# Loop over images and generate adversarial images
for filename in image_filenames:
    # Load image
    image_path = os.path.join(test_image_folder, filename)
    image = Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')

    image_np = np.array(image)

    # Create the FastGradientMethod attack object
    fgm = FastGradientMethod(estimator=estimator, eps=0.01, targeted=False)
    
    # Generate adversarial image using the FastGradientMethod attack
    adversarial_image_fgm = fgm.generate(image_np)
    # Create the ProjectedGradientDescent attack object
    pgd = ProjectedGradientDescent(estimator=estimator, eps=0.01, eps_step=0.005, max_iter=100, targeted=False)
    
    # Generate adversarial image using the ProjectedGradientDescent attack
    adversarial_image_pgd = pgd.generate(x=image_np)
    
    # Convert the adversarial images to numpy arrays
    adversarial_image_fgm = adversarial_image_fgm.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()
    adversarial_image_pgd = adversarial_image_pgd.squeeze(0).permute(1, 2, 0).numpy()
    
    # Convert pixel values from [0,1] to [0,255] and cast to uint8
    adversarial_image_fgm = np.uint8(adversarial_image_fgm * 255)
    adversarial_image_pgd = np.uint8(adversarial_image_pgd * 255)
    
    # Create output folder if it doesn't exist
    if not os.path.exists(output_folder):
        os.makedirs(output_folder)
    
    # Save the adversarial images in the output folder
    Image.fromarray(adversarial_image_fgm).save(os.path.join(output_folder, 'fgm_' + filename))
    Image.fromarray(adversarial_image_pgd).save(os.path.join(output_folder, 'pgd_' + filename))
```

The images are from the KITTI dataset in .jpg format.

I have tried transposing the image or resizing it, but it always throws the same error. Could it be that it has something to do with the PyTorch YOLOv5 and ART libraries not working together?